# What are the parameters for an administrator or supervisor password for BIOS?

Tags: bios, passwords, acer-aspire

I am trying to find documentation regarding the parameters for an administrator or supervisor password for an Acer Aspire A514-53. How long can it be? Can I use special characters, or just numbers and letters? I've already tried the community forums for Acer, without much success, and the documentation provided for the laptop is not of any help either.

Comment: what UEFI/BIOS is installed? common IFVs include AMI, Byosoft, Insyde Software or Phoenix Technologies.  https://uefi.org/node/4046

Comment: It is a Insyde Corp V. 1.16. Trying to find documentation on it, but nothing related to parameters for supervisor passwords.